# How can I bind to element attribute in jsview

Tags: javascript, jsviews

I have a label like below.
I wonder is it possible for jsview to support binding its title to its text?
Can I show the same text in its title?

```
<label title="">{^{for Owners}}{{:Name}}{^{if #index < #parent.data.length - 1}}&#59;{{/if}}&nbsp;{{/for}}</label>
```

The expected rendered result would be:

```
<label title="name1; name2; name3">name1; name2; name3</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using JsViews to data-link to elements, element attributes etc, you need to use the data-link attribute. When using JsViews `link` method (as opposed to JsRender `render` method) you can't nest `{{...}}` tags within element markup.

See http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link for a tutorial sequence on data-linking elements.

Using `data-link="expression"` is quite flexible, so there are a few alternative ways you can achieve your scenario. Here is a jsfiddle with three alternatives: http://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/j363W/.

It shows these three variants:

**Custom helper**

`<label data-link="title{:~listHelper(Owners, Owners.length)}">...`

`myTmpl.link("#content", data, {listHelper: function(arr) {
    return ...; // compute return value
}});`

**Data method**

`<label data-link="title{:nameList()}">...`

```
var data = {
    Owners:[{Name: "name1"}, {Name: "name2"}, {Name: "name3"}],
    nameList: function() {
    return ...; // compute return value
    },
    ... 
};

data.nameList.depends ="Owners.length";
```

**Custom JsViews tag**

`<label data-link="title{nameList Owners}">...`

```
$.views.tags("nameList", {
    render: function(Owners) {
        return ...; // compute return value
    },
    depends: "Owners.length"
});
```

See also https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/issues/255